# how to transform array into different array by extracting key values using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

How can I transform a big array into my won small array bu extracting keys and values using lodash.
The given array consists of nested arrays as well.

**Given array** ->

```
goals= [       
 { name: 'ACTIONS', levers: [ { partName: 'Improve', statuses: [ { element 1 },{ element 2 }]}] },
 { name: 'DEFINITIONS', levers: [ { partName: 'Hardwork', statuses: [ { element 1 },{ element 2 }]}] }    
]
```

Transform in to an array below :

```
resultantArray = 
    [
       { name: "ACTIONS",partName: "Improve", statuses: [ { element1 }, { element2 } ] },
       { name: "DEFINITIONS",partName: "hardwork", statuses: [ { element1 }, { element2 } ] }
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the example, I'm assuming that array under levers always contains only one element.

There is no real need to use lodash to solve this, all you need is a .map method and an access to object keys.

It can be done in pure JS, as well as lodash. Below are examples how to do it in both:

Pure JS:

```js
goals= [
    { name: 'ACTIONS', levers: [ { partName: 'Improve', statuses: [ { element: 1 },{ element: 2 }]}] },
    { name: 'DEFINITIONS', levers: [ { partName: 'Hardwork', statuses: [ { element: 1 },{ element: 2 }]}] }
]

resJS = goals.map(el => {
    return {
        name: el.name,
        partName: el.levers[0].partName,
        statuses: el.levers[0].statuses
    }
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(resJS,  undefined, 2))
```

Lodash:

```
const _ = require('lodash')

resLodash = _.map(goals, el => {
    return {
        name: _.get(el, 'name'),
        partName: _.get(el, 'levers[0].partName'),
        statuses: _.get(el, 'levers[0].statuses')
    }
})
```

Comment: The assumption is correct but unable to view you code result.

Comment: Just updated the answer and made Pure JS snippet runnable. I don't know how to create a runnable snippet using lodash though, but the output is the same.